# Union mount options in Fedora

Tags: fedora, aufs, union-mount

I've grown up a Debian/Ubuntu guy and I'm learning Fedora by trying to recreate the services my Ubuntu trusty box currently provides. However, I'm trying to recreate a union mount and don't see any obvious way to do it.

Each user on my Ubuntu-based server has a "media" folder, with subfolders for movies, music, etc. Using `aufs-tools`, I create a (read-only) union mount of userA...userZ's "media" folders at `/srv/media`. Then using Samba, my Plex box can access that combined media folder over the network.

It appears nothing reasonably resembling `aufs-tools` is available via the standard repos (nor via rpmfusion). I've seen some mentions online of UnionFS, but I also saw something about it having fallen out of favor. I don't want to use FUSE, because this union mount is based on several users' media folders. What's the preferred solution for creating union mounts on Fedora/RHEL/CentOS servers these days?

Answer (score 3):

Fedora tries to not deviate very far from the "mainline" upstream kernel from kernel.org. AuFS isn't in that kernel, so it isn't in Fedora.

We *do*, however, have an option: OverlayFS. Upstream documentation is [available on kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt), and here's some [quick examples](https://gist.github.com/amitsaha/d4f568e44c986c62ff96c63b88b0d9f4) on Fedora.

And, as pretty much always, the [Arch Linux documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Overlay_filesystem) is excellent and (as often the case) is applicable to Fedora as well. From that page, a line like this in `/etc/fstab` will do it:

```
overlay /merged overlay noauto,x-systemd.automount,lowerdir=/lower,upperdir=/upper,workdir=/work 0 0
```

Comment: Note that overlayfs is available in recent RHEL (7.1+) as a tech preview (and therefore also recent CentOS).

Comment: Note that OverlayFS is total crap compared to AuFS

Comment: "Total crap" or not, it's available in the mainline kernel and thus supportable and sustainable, while AuFS is not. (Also, "total crap" is untrue.)